# oracle sql developer: 00904. 00000 - "%s: invalid identifier". Where is my fault?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying find my fault. 
I am getting this error message:

> SQL-Fehler: ORA-00904: "S1"."PARTNO": ungültiger Bezeichner
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

I have checked my database and all tables exist.

Here is my sql code:

```
select s1.*
 , p.city as "Produktionsort" 
 , p.partname
from (select count(s.partno) as "Anzahl_Produktarten"
        , s.partno as "Partno" 
      from company.supp_part_job s 
      group by s.partno ) s1
 , company.part p 
where s1.partno IN (select p1.partno from company.part p1 where p1.city != 'London') 
   and p.partno = s1.partno 
group by s1.partno
```

Comment: Is `partno` the right spelling? Could be a typo error.

Comment: yes, it is. i have used 'partno' in other sql queries and there are no problems.

Answer (score 5):

Because you aliased in the inner select (s1) `partno` as `"Partno"` you must refer to it as case sensitive in the outer query:

```
select s1.*
 , p.city as "Produktionsort" 
 , p.partname
from (select count(s.partno) as "Anzahl_Produktarten"
        , s.partno as "Partno" 
      from company.supp_part_job s 
      group by s.partno ) s1
 , company.part p 
where s1."Partno" IN (select p1.partno from company.part p1 where p1.city != 'London') 
   and p.partno = s1."Partno" 
group by s1."Partno"
```

Comment: @user3617496 - did you change all three references?

Comment: @user3617496 - well running that code doesn't get that error; it does get an `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression` - you have no aggregate in the outer query so you don't need the final `group by` at all. You won't get the same error you had before; certainly not with the same identifier.

Answer (score 2):

If you put double quotes around a column name, it will make it case sensitive. So I would think this line:

```
s.partno as "Partno"
```

is creating a case-sensitive s1."Partno" but the `where` clause is looking for s1.partno.  Try removing the double quotes from your column aliases.

Comment: @user3617496 - [the queries from both answers are valid](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7b5c9/1) if the extra `group by` is removed. If you made this change you can't be getting exactly the same error.